# ASP MVC.NET3 Local IIS7 object reference error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

During development of an mvc web application, I'm encourtering issues running the local instance of the site. When I try to reload a page, after a successful first load, I'm seeing the below error. If I run the site through the VS virtual server, there are no issues. My app pool is running in integrated mode and it is running .net 4. Any idea why this is occurring? Is this enough information?

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>     System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.Get(String name) +109
>     System.Web.Mvc.UrlRewriterHelper.WasThisRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext) +59
>     System.Web.Mvc.PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +213
>     System.Web.Mvc.PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +168
>     System.Web.Mvc.PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +148
>     LeadManager.Web.UI.Helpers.MenuHelper.GenerateUrl(String url) in C:\Development\Hg\LeadManager\Web.UI\Helpers\MenuHelper.cs:1132
>     LeadManager.Web.UI.Helpers.MenuHelper.BuildLeadManagementMenu(Menu navMenu, Agent agent) in C:\Development\Hg\LeadManager\Web.UI\Helpers\MenuHelper.cs:554
>     LeadManager.Web.UI.Helpers.MenuHelper.AddNavMenu(Agent agent) in C:\Development\Hg\LeadManager\Web.UI\Helpers\MenuHelper.cs:530
>     ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Development\Hg\LeadManager\Web\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml:115
>     System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +279
>     System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +103
>     System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +172
>     System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +88
>     System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +233
>     System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +233
>     System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +377
>     System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +32
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +748196
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +748196
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +748160
>     System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +334
>     System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5() +62
>     System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +15
>     System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d() +52
>     System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +437
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +354

MenuHelper is used to build navigation menus. The code that fails is the return statement outside of the if:

```
private static string GenerateUrl(string url)
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        // hack to enable using this on old web forms pages
        return UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(url, new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
    }
    return (new UrlHelper(instance.htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext)).Content(url);
}

private static string GenerateUrl(string actionName, string controllerName)
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        // hack to enable using this on old web forms pages
        return GenerateUrl(String.Format("{0}/{1}", controllerName, actionName));
    }

    if (instance.htmlHelper == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("htmlHelper has not been populated.");
    if (instance.htmlHelper.ViewContext == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ViewContext has not been populated.");
    if (instance.htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("RequestContext has not been populated.");

    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(instance.htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    if (urlHelper == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("UrlHelper has not been populated.");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("actionName has not been populated.");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("controllerName has not been populated.");

    return (urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName));
}
```

Comment: What is your MenuHelper.GenerateUrl doing? Can you post your code?

Comment: i updated the question with a code sample

Comment: Nobody can tell you why your object is null. I would suggest to run the app and then attach to the process to debug and see what's going on.

Comment: @Kate there is no object reference error when debugging, it works fine. it appears that UrlHelper is the culprit and the error only appears once i've navigated to an MVC page then back to an aspx page.

Comment: I am currently facing a *very* similar issue with urlhelper in the mix as well.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well, though only with a certain version of my site. In my case, it seems to be a problem with the binary, not IIS's configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue, it was the IIS7 URL Rewrite Module. I'm not sure why or how but I solved the problem by uninstalling it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm seeing this while on shared hosting. Any idea if it can be disabled via config somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue too, and indeed uninstalling the IIS7 URL Rewrite Module would help fix it. The problem is we've always had the Rewrite module installed on all our servers which made me a bit nervous. So I looked into it a bit more to see what I had changed to cause this, and it turned out it was me. In fact I've done this a few times before and don't seem to learn because it's an easy thing to do.

My class took in the UrlHelper as a dependency through the constructor like such

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
   private readonly UrlHelper _url;

   public MyClass(UrlHelper url)
   {
      _url = url;
   }

   public RedirectResult RedirectMeSomewhere()
   {
      return new RedirectResult(_url.Action("MyAction", "MyController"));
   }
}
```

and my Ninject binding looked like this

```
Bind<IMyInterface>()
   .To<MyClass>()
   .InSingletonScope();
```

where as it should have looked like this so it serves the correct UrlHelper for the request, instead of an already disposed one that was created as a singleton when the site was first hit.

```
Bind<IMyInterface>()
   .To<MyClass>()
   .InRepositoryScope();
```

It just takes a while to notice these things, I need to come up with a test to ensure that the UrlHelper isn't served up in a singleton.

**tl:dr**

My Ninject binding for a class that took the UrlHelper as a dependency through its constructor was set to `SingletonScope()` instead of `RequestScope()`, which is very bad for obvious reasons..

Anyways, hope that helps someone (or me in the future).

Answer (score -1):

So this is the line that is failing:

```
return (new UrlHelper(instance.htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext)).Content(url);
```

We know that instance isn't null due to the line above that already checks for null.  Null reference exceptions are the most common unhandled exceptions and are also the easiest to avoid.  In general, you should never assume properties or parameters that are nullable types are not null.  My guess is that instance.htmlHelper is your problem.  I am assuming that htmlHelper is an instance of System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.  Therefore, ViewContext and RequestContext *should* not be null if that is a valid HtmlHelper created by MVC.

The simple solution is to check for nulls like this:

```
if (instance.htmlHelper == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("htmlHelper has not been populated.");
}

return (new UrlHelper(instance.htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext)).Content(url);
```

Obviously you could repeat this for ViewContext and RequestContext by MVC should populate those.

Now assuming htmlHelper is null (the most likely situation), you have a slight design problem here.  What you should really be doing is extending the HtmlHelper class and not using a static method.  Also, you seem to be using some kind of static instance which is probably also not valid in MVC.  MVC *typically* instantiates controllers and views for each request.  You can still use the static method for a web forms implementation, but for MVC you should extend HtmlHelper like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GenerateUrl(this htmlHelper, string url)
{
    return (new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext)).Content(url);
}
```

Make sure you are always using the currently active HtmlHelper from MVC and not some static instance.  I'm not sure off the top of my head if ViewContext or RequestContext could be null after a request has been completed.  I've never tried to persist an HtmlHelper after one request.  Even if they aren't null, they could otherwise be invalid and be causing your problem further down in the MVC pipeline.

Hope that helps.

Comment: very detailed reply, thank you. i updated the code to check more properties and it still fails on this line **return (urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName));**. how does that even make sense? what else could be null? also remember, this is not a problem when i'm executing within the asp.net development server and it does not bomb until i visit a MVC page then return to a .aspx page.

Comment: this guy apparently has a similar issue: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640950/null-reference-exception-when-generating-a-url-with-urlhelper-action-method]. he determined that "the HttpServerVarsCollection was Disposed, along with it's parent HttpRequest object."

Comment: That was kind of my point of using extension methods and not a static instance of something.  I think if passed in your htmlHelper instead of storing a static instance your problem would go away.  If you used an extension method, your web forms version would just call it like instance.htmlHelper.GenerateUrl(actionName, controllerName).